# SDL Campaign Integration with Tridion

Tags: content-manager, sdl-tridion

I am trying to integrate SDL Campaign Manager with SDL Tridion, all I wanted to do is import audience data to campaign and segment it and post back the segment information back to Audience manager DB.

Documentation around integration is confusing http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/Integration%20guide%20for%20SDL%20Campaigns%20and%20SDL%20Tridion-v1/GUID-D47E199A-3519-4252-AB80-E74C79B6266D#docid=GUID-D5364CA7-5BD5-4E46-B0C8-C291BD8D9510&filename=GUID-D5364CA7-5BD5-4E46-B0C8-C291BD8D9510.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-D5364CA7-5BD5-4E46-B0C8-C291BD8D9510

I have configured kettle jobs in PDI (pentaho data integration) and able to import export from audience manager service however I am not able to find out how this data can be used in SDL Campaigns also documentation around OmniTactic is confusing it doesn't give any idea how it can be segmented and send back.

Any pointers will be really helpful.

Regards,
Sameer Jamal